# transform SVG string to Bitmap ideally in memory in C#

Tags: c#, svg, bitmap

I am using the code below to transform a SVG string (svgString) to a Bitmap (myBitmap). Ideally, I want to avoid the round-trip to the hard drive. Do you think this is possible (did not find much documentation the SVG nuget package). By the way, I know that I can also write a bmp to the hard drive but I chose png as the background of a bmp is always black for some reason.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using Svg;

namespace Bla
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var svgPath = @"d:\test.svg";
      var pngPath = @"d:\test.png";
      var svgString = @"
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <body>
      <svg height='200' width='500'>
        <polyline points='20,20 40,25 60,40 80,120 120,140 200,180' style='fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3' />
        Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
      </svg>
      </body>
      </html>
      ";

      File.WriteAllText(svgPath, svgString);

      var svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(svgPath);  
      svgDocument.ShapeRendering = SvgShapeRendering.Auto;

      var bmp = svgDocument.Draw();              
      bmp.Save(pngPath, ImageFormat.Png);

      var myBitmap = new Bitmap(pngPath);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library but I [see an overload of `Open` that takes a stream.](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG/blob/master/Source/SvgDocument.cs)

Comment: There is also `FromSVG()`

Comment: thanks will have a look but please feel free to post answer.

Comment: How would I use FromSVG? not sure what the generic is for. attempt SvgDocument.FromSvg<Bitmap>(svgString)

Comment: [Here's a unit test in the project](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG/blob/master/Tests/Svg.UnitTests/SvgTextTests.cs) that demonstrates one way to get an svg document from a string. But I would think `FromSVG` would be easier, did you try it? The compiler should be able to determine the generic type so just call it like any method.

Comment: Thanks - sorry to ignorant to figure how to use FromSVG - see previous comment

Comment: I don't have a development environment at the moment. try `var thesvgdoc = SvgDocument.FromSVG("your svg string...");` or `var thesvgdoc = SvgDocument.FromSVG<SvgDocument>("your svg string...");`

Comment: amazing only one line of code: SvgDocument.FromSvg<SvgDocument>(svgString).Draw()!

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks feel free to past answer and I delete mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an SvgDocument from a string with `var mySvg = SvgDocument.FromSvg<SvgDocument>(svgString);` which you can then draw to a Bitmap with the Draw() method provided by the SvgDocument, like so `var myBmp = mySvg.Draw();` All without touching the hard disk.

Comment: This seems to work using the answers provided by everyone else

var svgDocument = SvgDocument.FromSvg<SvgDocument>(svgString);
            svgDocument.ShapeRendering = SvgShapeRendering.Auto;
            byte[] BitmapData;
            using(Bitmap bmp = svgDocument.Draw())
            {
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
                    BitmapData = stream.ToArray();
                }
            }

Comment: @tottaka edit your answer to include that code. OP is having trouble with the svg part, not the bitmap part.

Comment: @Crowcoder You're right, I should have read the code more carefully to understand what was trying to be achieved. Just updated my answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you read [SvgDocument.cs](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG/blob/master/Source/SvgDocument.cs#L253), you can find 'SvgDocument.Open(path)', so I write the following method.

```
private void TextToBitmap(string text)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            svgDoc = SvgDocument.Open<SvgDocument>(stream, null);
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = svgDoc.Draw();
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use the function to load SVG from **Stream** without saving to files. Next step is to save it as **PNG** file.

```
public static void LoadSVG(string coinName)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://linktogetfile.com/" + coinName.ToUpper() + ".svg");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.ContentType = "image/png";
        request.Accept = "image/webp,image/apng";
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        try
        {
            SvgDocument svgDoc = SvgDocument.Open<SvgDocument>(stream);
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = svgDoc.Draw(rasterWidth: 24, rasterHeight: 24);
            bitmap.Save("mfile.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
        catch (Exception ex1)
        {
            //Error handling
        }
    }
```