# How to save file on server

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I have .net framework web forms that needs to save pdf. But I can't save that to wanted location because application is ran through IISExpres and I cant acces my project directories. This is on localhost but will eventually be on server.

This is code that accepts svg string from javascript.

```
    [WebMethod()]
    public static List<string> sendEmail(string svgStr)
    {
        List<string> ret = new List<string>();

        string savePath = Path.Combine("some path", "file.pdf");
        var options = new PdfSaveOptions();
        //this converts svg string to pdf
        //instead of path, there can be passed memory stream provider
        //which is extended from Aspose.Html.IO.ICreateStreamProvider
        //but i dont know how to use this like memory stream
        Converter.ConvertSVG(svgStr, ".", options, savePath);

        ret.Add("proslo je");
        return ret;
    }
```

Edit: I managed to get the pdf to memory stream and use it later. Thanks for help.

Comment: Either make function for download desired pdf, or store it in MemoryStream. Do not save it on the local disc with web application. Its totally wrong approach.

Comment: I have svg from client side, which I need to convert to pdf. I tried using aspose for this, but can't get it to memory stream.

Comment: Please show the entire code that shows how you store that file, and in what format you get it. Then maybe i will be able to help you with writing required code to load it into memory stream. You need also give a reason, why you ever want that file to be saved in local disc ? What you want to achieve?

Comment: I added part of code that should handle this, I don't know if this is enough.

Comment: i think similar question were already solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53903784/transform-svg-string-to-bitmap-ideally-in-memory-in-c-sharp

Comment: But I don't think I can save this as pdf to memory stream?

Comment: you can put in memory stream any kind of data, in any format. Memory stream is not a limitation here. The only limitation are functions/classes that you are using. I also dont know what's inside the interface `ICreateStreamProvider` so its hard to say with so few informations provided in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the path is accessible via the internet not at a lower level than the application that is running it you just need to map the web path to the underlying server path.

```
var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/download/" +filename);
```

This will take the path from the root of the website.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to provide the required permissions on the target folder for the account running the application. A guide on how to do so can be found here: https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/set-file-folder-permissions-windows/